# react refresh defaultValue

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

**Edit:  another way to solve this would be:  is there a way to only filter inputs on native onchange (blur or enter key)**

I have an input with a minimum of 1 ( this minimum changes and is enforced by javascript ).

I can't use

`<input value={@state.myfield} onChange={@customOnChange} />`

because, when they hit backspace, it defaults to one.

lets say the value is 9
user hits backspace so they can change it to 8
input now says 18

This is not intended behavior.

So, i'm using

`<input defaultValue={@state.myfield} onChange={@customOnChange} />`

instead.  This enforced the correct values behind the scenes, but it never updates the dom with the corrected min/max.

**Can I manually trigger react to reset `defaultValue` and look them up again?**

I'd like to re-populate the input field when the user `blur`s or `e.keyCode==13`s

I could do it like this, but it seems super messy

```
if @respondToNativeChange
  elProp = value: @state.myfield
else
  elProp = defaultValue: @state.myfield
<input onChange={@customOnChange}
  onKeyDown={(e) => if e.keyCode is 13 then @respondToNativeChange = true; @forceUpdate()}
  onBlur={@respondToNativeChange=true;@forceUpdate()}
  {...elProp} />
```

I could also do it after the fact but also having to attach some data-attr prop

```
componentDidMount: ->

  $(@getDOMNode()).find('input').blur (e) => $(e.target).val @state[$(e.target).attr('data-attr')
```

but both seem too messy.

Is there a way to trigger react to re-populate the defaultValue into all inputs or specific ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to filter only when the native onchange happens, I wrote a mixin to listen to native on change.

```
myMixins.nativeOnChange = (method) ->

  unless _.isFunction method
    method = @[method]

  return nativeOnChange: (attribute, val, m) ->

    # Override CB
    if _.isString m
      m = @[m]
    else unless _.isFunction m
      m = method

    @_noc ?= {}

    ob = {
      onKeyDown: (e) =>
        if e.keyCode is 13
          @_noc[attribute] = true
          m?.call this, e, attribute, $(e.target).val()

      onBlur: (e) =>
        @_noc[attribute] = true
        m?.call this, e, attribute, $(e.target).val()
    }
    # Here, we detect if we should force dom to update by using `value`
    if @_noc[attribute]
      delete @_noc[attribute]
      ob.value = val
    else
      ob.defaultValue = val

    ob
```

And then to implement it

```
MyFactory = React.createFactory React.createClass

  mixins: [
    mixins.nativeOnChange ->
      @forceUpdate()
  ]

  onChange: (attribute, method) -> (e) =>

    val = $(e.target).val()
    if method then val = method val
    # You can limit it here and manipulate it
    # the changes won't get picked up until the nativeOnChange
    # forces value: to populate the dom
    @state[attribute] = val
    @forceUpdate() # is safe here, because defaultValue will be used
    # until nativeOnChange forces value

  render: ->
    <div>
      {props = @nativeOnChange 'min', @state.min}
      <input
        className='form-control input-control'
        name='min'
        type='number'
        step=1
        min=1
        max=10
        onChange={@onChange 'min', @parseInt}
        {...props}
      />
    </div>
```

So using it in views is fairly easy now.  It's somewhat complex so if someone knows a better way to do native onchanges, I'm all ears...................  oh wait.. is there an `htmlOnChange`............